# How to write a email to HOD of the company seeking support

Tags: professionalism, management, colleagues, email, company-culture

Help me with quotes and lines for sending a official mail to all the department heads of my company, seeking a good support from their end.

I joined in a new company so everyone should know about me and my work credentials.

Comment: What is HOD? How many people are we talking about? What kind of support? Why don't you write a proposal here instead of letting others do all your work? Do you think these people will appreciate getting the mail?

Comment: HOD - head of the department,, i joined in a new company so everyone should know about me and my work credentials..

Comment: Don't  You don't need to tell all department heads "I'm here", not even a single one. What do you think this would be good for, other than getting you the first impression "I'm annoying and like to waste time"?

Comment: @deviantfan That should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 7):

Don't.

You don't need to tell all department heads "I'm here", not even a single one. What do you think this would be good for, other than getting you the first impression "I'm annoying and like to waste time"?

An introduction to the people sitting in the same office as you etc. is ok.
Contacting some other department head because you need something work-related, and telling him/her your name and that you're working on XY in department Z on this occassion, is ok too.
Doing this without work-related reason is just wasting time (work time you're all are paid for) and distracts the other people from their real work. Most people won't appreciate it.

If the company is small enough, you'll eventually get to know everyone anyways. Don't rush it.
If the company is too large for that, there no reason at all that all department heads know you and/or you know them, because department heads usually don't work directly with employees from other departments [depending on the company, this may be not allowed at all] and can't even remember every single employee.